# How do you compare US and UK PhD programs?

Tags: phd, research-process, united-states, united-kingdom

I have an equal opportunity to pursue my PhD in chemistry in the United States or United Kingdom. As I investigated, the educations systems are different (correct me if I'm wrong):

**US**

- BSc: 4-year coursework
- MSc: 1-year coursework + 1-year research
- PhD: 2-year coursework + 2-year research

**UK**

- BSc: 3-year coursework
- MSc: (it can be) 2-year research
- PhD: 4-year research

In all programs I checked, a master degree is required for the PhD admission (I think it is the standard for chemistry).

My ultimate goal is to continue in academia and I anticipate that I need 3-4 years of postdoc before applying for a faculty position. Since the UK system is more research active, I thought a research degree can be more helpful to get a postdoc position (I anticipate I can publish more papers during 4 years as opposed to two years of research in the US).

In general, I am fascinated by the research-oriented system in UK and I prefer it to coursework, but it can be my misconception only. This is the reason that I ask this question to avoid any illusion.

*Disclaimer:* I know that a PhD program may take longer and each university may have different programs to offer. These numbers are just standard averages for the sake of comparison.

Comment: The number of people who have taken PhDs both in the US and in the UK might be very small.